# Can't use custom recipe with .Net Core

Tags: jsreport

I have followed the instruction to install a custom recipe in .Net here: https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local but I can't make it work.

1. I have created a jsreport into my project folder (where the .csproj is stored)
2. I have created the jsreport.config.json into the jsreport folder.
3. I have installed electron-pdf using "npm install electron-pdf" into the jsreport folder
4. I used xcopy to copy this folder on build to the output directory.
5. Upon build, I can see in \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0 the jsreport folder, with the jsreport.config.json file and the node_modules folder in it.

I still get:

```
Error during rendering report: Recipe 'electron-pdf' not found
```

When I specifiy

```
HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.ElectronPdf);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. I had to install `jsreport-electron-pdf` in addition to `electron-pdf` (both NPM packages are needed).